# How to attach authorization header via PHP?

Tags: php, json

I am using PHP to get JSON from a remote server via `file_get_contents` command. Here is the piece of code I used:

```
$opts = array(
  'https'=>array(
    'method'=>'GET',
    'header'=>'Accept-language: en\r\n' .
              'Authorization: MAC ["3","ios2.5.0","123","123abc","123=","abc="]\r\n' .
              'User-Agent: abc/1.1.1 iOS/10.0.2 iPhone/iPhone7,1\r\n'
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$file = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/v11/file?search=ios&with=users%2Cfiles%2Cquestions', false, $context);

echo $file;
```

I did a quick debugging:

1. Using Postman I was able to get the json file with the same header.
2. I tried a different json from a different url, it works.
3. I tried a local file, it works.

Comment: Move `\r\n` into double quotes - `Accept-language: en' . "\r\n" .`

Comment: @nogad it's not Google. For the purpose of the demo I changed the url.

Comment: @labue it didn't work

Comment: @JamesWayne, what response are you receiving?  Did you update all instances of `"\r\n"` ?

Comment: I got no response (empty file). Yes.

Comment: @labue Oh and I tried the simple PHP on MacOS too, and it failed because of SSL error, I don't know how to add certificate to the simple PHP server so I had to use MAMP Pro. I use the same certificate for MAMP as I used for Postman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to understand what `file_get_contents` is. This command is a request to get the file on the server, in this case it is requesting to get `https://www.google.com/v11/file/index.html` on the server as in one single step. Since your url seems to use header to verify your origin, it might be an ajax request, meaning the server components didn't set up to allow an output from `file_get_contents` requests, instead they probably accept cURL requests.

So you can use:

```
curl_exec()
```